# How to enable -fpermissive for a section of code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a C single-header library that I would like to use in my C++ project. Normally, I would just include the file and that would be fine because C++ is *almost* a superset of C. However, this library has a `goto` that jumps over an initialization, violating the C++ standard.

I can get around this be enabling the `-fpermissive` compiler flag on GCC, but I want the errors to trigger properly for the rest of my code.

Is there a way I can enable it just for this one header file (perhaps similar to `#pragma GCC diagnostic XXX`).

Comment: You could wrap all calls to your C single-header library into "trampoline functions" in a separate C or C++ file which is compiled with `-fpermissive` exclusively (and link this to the rest). But, actually, I would prevent such tricks and fix the issues by their roots... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's [`#pragma GCC optimize "blah"`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas) or the function attribute `__attribute__((optimize("blah")))` that act like the argument `-fblah` was given for the rest of that file/that specific function, but it doesn't seem to work with `-fpermissive`:

```
$ cat foo.cpp
#pragma GCC optimize "permissive"

void foo(int x) {
}
$ g++-8 -c -Wall -Wextra foo.cpp
foo.cpp:1:22: warning: bad option ‘-fpermissive’ to pragma ‘optimize’ [-Wpragmas]
 #pragma GCC optimize "permissive"
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:3:16: warning: bad option ‘-fpermissive’ to attribute ‘optimize’ [-Wattributes]
  void foo(int x) {
```

One option would be to put the function that needs this in a file by itself, and configure your build system to compile just that file with `-fpermissive`, though that breaks the header-only model. Or fix the code so it doesn't need that option at all.

Answer (score 1):

Per gcc man page:

> -fpermissive
>
> Downgrade some diagnostics about nonconformant code from errors to warnings.  Thus, using -fpermissive allows some nonconforming code to compile.

So in theory, one can allow a section to compile as permissive using a sequence of gcc warning pragmas:

```
   //  Start permissive code
#pragma GCC diagnostic push

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-result"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
   // .. Other #pragmas

   // Permissive Code here.

   // Restore normal processing.
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

One challenge is that there is no published list of errors that will be ignored with `-fpermissive` (At least I could not find it). One possible approach will be to compile the code, and enter the '#pragma's one at at a time, until the code compiles cleanly.

If one can identify all (or most) of the rules, possible to put them into #include file.

```
#pragma GCC diagostic push
#include "permissive.h"
   // Permissive Code here
#pragma GCC diagostic pop
```

Comment: I tried this by ignoring `-Wjump-misses-init`, but apparently that is only available for C code, not C++. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html